# MongoDb multi collection transactions do not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to update two collections. I want to make sure that either both the collections get updated or they don't.

I created this simple example of two updates (both of them use same collection here, but they could be different):

```
       await this.client.connect();
    const session = this.client.startSession();

    try{
      const transactionOptions = {
        readPreference: 'primary',
        readConcern: { level: 'local' },
        writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }
    };

    await session.withTransaction(async () => {
    await this.client.db("Person").collection("persons").updateMany({ "phone":  "23138213"}, {$set: {"gender": "F10"} });
    await this.client.db("Person").collection("persons").updateMany({ "phone":  "23138213"},  "d");
  }, transactionOptions)
}
  finally{
    await session.endSession();

  }
```

Now if the initial value of gender was empty `""`.  Then after executing the above code, the final value should still be `""` because the second update is invalid syntax and would throw exception.

But the result is `gender:Male`

Comment: Why do you have await and a callback on the same invocation?

Comment: My guess is you are misusing the driver api, reference the docs in question and ensure you are following them correctly.

Comment: @D.SM I have removed the callback. It was wrong. I have updated the post.  But that doesn't answer why it doesn't work. I did follow the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/
I don't think I am missing anything. Am I?

Comment: You are not passing session to the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to solve it based on @D. SM's valuable comments.

```
    await this.client.connect();
    const session = this.client.startSession();

    try{
      const transactionOptions = {
        readPreference: 'primary',
        readConcern: { level: 'local' },
        writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }
    };
    await session.withTransaction(async () => {
    await this.client.db("Person").collection("persons").updateMany({ "phone":  "23138213"}, {$set: {"gender": "G2"} }, { session });
    await this.client.db("Person").collection("persons").updateMany({ "phone":  "23138213"},  "G2", { session });
  }, transactionOptions)
}
  finally{
    await session.endSession();
  }
```

Even after passing session to the updates, the transaction didn't seem to work. The issue was that I was supposed to wrap it within `{}`

```
await this.client.db("Person").collection("persons").updateMany({ "phone":  "23138213"}, {$set: {"gender": "G2"} }, { session });
```

**Instead of**

```
await this.client.db("Person").collection("persons").updateMany({ "phone":  "23138213"}, {$set: {"gender": "G2"} }, session );
```